# Python variable in global namespace not being updated by augmented assignment in function in class namespace

Tags: python, namespaces, global-variables, instance-variables

I'm trying to update a counter variable by one each time a certain value stays the same.

The main conditional is this:

```
streak = 0
entryno_counter = 1

class OtherDataGet:
streak_type = 3
uod_state = 3

    @staticmethod
    def uod():
        global streak
        if entryno_counter == 1:
            pass
        else:
            if values[1] > values_cache[1]:  # If value went up
                if OtherDataGet.uod_state == 1 or 2:  # If it was previously down or same
                    OtherDataGet.uod_state = 0  # Set state to up
                    streak = 0  # Reset streak
                    OtherDataGet.streak_type = 0  # Set streak type to up
                elif OtherDataGet.uod_state == 0:  # If last state was up
                    streak += 1  # Add one to streak counter
                return 0
            elif values[1] < values_cache[1]:
                if OtherDataGet.uod_state == 0 or 2:
                    OtherDataGet.uod_state = 1
                    streak = 0
                    OtherDataGet.streak_type = 1
                elif OtherDataGet.uod_state == 1:
                    streak += 1
                return 1
            elif values[1] == values_cache[1]:
                if OtherDataGet.uod_state == 0 or 1:
                    OtherDataGet.uod_state = 2
                    streak = 0
                    OtherDataGet.streak_type = 2
                elif OtherDataGet.uod_state == 2:
                    streak += 1
                return 2
```

The variable that is being updated is in the global namespace, and is accessible everywhere so there should be no problem in updating it.

For example, when a 2 is returned the first time, the streak counter is set to 0, the second time a 2 is returned, it should be set to 1, the third time a 2 is returned, it should be a 3, etc.

1,125519,0,182701,4,404,**0,1**
2,125519,2,182702,4,404,**2,1**
3,125518,1,182703,4,404,**1,1**
4,125519,0,182704,4,404,**0,1**
5,125519,2,182705,4,404,**2,1**
6,125519,2,182706,4,404,**2,1**
7,125519,2,182706,4,404,**2,1**
8,125519,2,182707,4,404,**2,1**
9,125517,1,182708,4,404,**1,1**
10,125518,0,182709,4,404,**0,1**
11,125517,1,182710,4,404,**1,1**

This is the output data, all you need to look at is the last two columns. The second to last is the returned value from `OtherDataGet.uod`, and the last one should be `streak`. If you look at lines 5-8, there is a streak of 2s, and the last value on the line should be 1, 2, 3, 4 respectively, but it it's staying as 1 even when it should be reset to 0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using global variables in a function other than the one that created them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare the variable globally inside of any function you want to use it in. EG:

```
def uod():
    global streak
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try to assign to a global variable inside a function, it creates a local variable instead. To prevent this from happening, use the `global` keyword inside your function.

In this case, that would be:

```
def uod():
    global streak, entryno_counter
```

And the rest as normal.

Comment: My bad, there was a mistake in how the code was copied, it is declared as global at the top of the function, and still doesn't work.